# Pseudonym of a graffiti artist

Tags: names, nicknames

What do you call a **pseudonym** of a **street art/graffiti artist**?

Word *'pseudonym'* is too general.
So I need exactly something like *'[street] artist pseudonym'*, but also not *'tag'* or *'nickname'*.

To the point, Sammie Cox is my pseudonym for artworks, and I want to complete that sentence with that context:

> My real name is Krzysztof Kowalski, but my *[the term]* is Sammie Cox.

So, which term is the most correct?

Comment: *Nom de spraycan*?

Comment: *Nom de aeroselle?* (Obviously both @TimLymington and I are alluding to *nom de plume* as a writer's pseudonym)

Comment: Or how about "nom de graffiti"?

Comment: How about, "nom de vandalisme"? Or "nom de tagging"?

Comment: My earlier comment (which I deleted) was made in a spirit of jesting. No offense intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moniker** or **alias** would fit well, I think. They are essentially the same for your purposes, with the latter being a bit more formal.

In the specific context of graffiti I would also consider **street name**.

Comment: I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a graffiti artist who refers to his moniker. (Unless he is simultaneously a 1930s gangster …)

Comment: i was suggesting "street name" just as you were beating me too it. "moniker" and "alias" as well as "nom de plumb" are all usable, less so as the order progresses, but they don't quite feel appropriate to associate with the art/graffiti medium.

Comment: @DavidM  I agree that thugs who scribble on walls wouldn't use **moniker**, but it's actually used pretty frequently with some of the "greats" like Banksy, Ever, Faith47, Mr. Brainwash  and others.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can grant that. Particularly for Brits (?) like Banksy.

Comment: Also, didn't mean to attempt a one-up of your answer. My phone didn't show yours until after I hit post.

Comment: @miercoledi I would generally agree, with the caveat that the name they deserve depends on their talent and respect. A gangster that sprays "TJ Northside" or something lame on an apartment building is nothing more than a thug. If the piece is truly artistic, I feel they deserve the term moniker and, if they chose, nom de plumb. You have to earn two names.

Comment: @DavidM no offense taken! I think we'd both agree street name is probably the safest word to use.

Answer (score 1):

*Pseudonym* is fine.

*Street name* is often used, too.

*Tag* refers to either a signature people leave on larger works (and can be their pseudonym), or it is a very low grade form of graffito often little more than someone's initials or name.

Graffiti artists are still artists, (the legality of their chosen medium aside). So, pseudonym is always appropriate.

Of note [Wikipedia on pseudonyms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym) specifically refers to graffiti artist's tags as a type of pseudonym.